# How to get data from distributed table

Tags: distributed, clickhouse

If I have a table, which structure was updated (ie system.query_log after latest update), but somehow distributed "view" has still old structure, how I could query data of new columns from that from entire cluster?

What I meant:

If you have distributed table, it could be done easily by:

`select count(1) from distributed_query_log where event_date = '2019-01-24'`

But `select Settings.names, Settings.values from distributed_query_log where event_date = '2019-01-24' limit 1\G` will fail, because it does not have those fields, when system.query_log has:

`select Settings.names, Settings.values from system.query_log where event_date = '2019-01-24' limit 1\G`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Clickhouse release [1.1.54362](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/changelog/#clickhouse-release-1-1-54362-2018-03-11) was added function `cluster`.

So, you can do it by:

```
select Settings.names, Settings.values from cluster('CLUSTER_TITLE', 'system.query_log') where event_date = '2019-01-24' limit 1\G
```

Where `CLUSTER_TITLE` - your cluster's title.

Thanks: [Alexander Bocharov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7539706/alexander-bocharov)

Answer (score 1):

In general case: after changing the underlying table you need to recreate (or alter) Distributed table.

Comment: indeed, but in case when all of your SREs are busy, `cluster` function is ready to help :)